# Contrast Enhancement For An Image Using A Gaussian Function

Tags: computer-vision

I am working on a program that involves detecting faces in photos, i am reading a paper that someone has wrote and they said that they had more success detecting faces once he they applied some enhancements to the image, one of these being a contrast enhancement. The exact words are...

> Contrast enhancement improves the overall quality of the image. Gaussian convolution using 
>   the Gaussian function G(x, y) is first applied with the input value channel image in the HSV 
>   space. The convolution process can be expressed as follows

They then give you Equation 3: $V_{con} = V_1(x,y) \oplus G(x,y)$ NOTE: $V_1$ is the original value

> $V_{CON}$ in Eq. 3 denotes the convolution result, which contains the luminance information from 
>   the surrounding pixels. The center pixel value is now compared with the Gaussian convolution 
>   result in order to find the amount of contrast enhancement of that center pixel. This process is 
>   described by the following equation

Equation 4: $V_{ce}(x,y) = 255V_{le}(x,y)^{E(x,y)}$ NOTE: $V_{le}$ is the result of another enhancement done previously.

> where $V_{CE}(x, y)$ is the result of contrast enhancement and $E(x, y)$ is given by the following relation

$E(x,y) = (V_{con}(x,y)/V_1(x,y))^g$

> Here g is the image dependent parameter determined by using the standard deviation of the 
>   input value channel image. If the center pixel is brighter then the surrounding pixels, the contrast 
>   of the pixel is pulled up. On the other hand, if the center pixel is darker then the neighboring 
>   pixel then the contrast of the pixel is lowered.

The problem is that with my understanding of maths (NCEA Level 3, Last year at collage) i don't understand how to do the first part, any help would be much appreciated

The full paper is here: http://jips-k.org/dlibrary/JIPS_v09_no1_paper9.pdf

Comment: _Convolution_ (for which they are using "$\oplus$") just takes a weighted average of the pixels surrounding $x,y$.  In the case of a _gaussian convolution_ the weights are given by a gaussian distribution (the bell-shaped curve from probability).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter.

Answer (score 3):

Convolution is a relatively simple operation to perform, but to make it fast involves a little extra work ([Wikipedia article on convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)). In general, if you convolve a discretized function F by a different discretized function G, you are simply performing the following operation:

$$(F\otimes G)(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^NF(x-i)*G(i)$$

Where N is the number of discrete values of G. Notice this is effectively just summing the product of F and G "centered" around $x$.

In 2D (which is what an image is), this looks like:

$$(F\otimes G)(x,y) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^N\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^MF(x-i,y-j)*G(i,j)$$

The paper you're reading tells you that F is the V channel of the image in HSV space, and G is a 2D gaussian function. Code-wise, the above form should translate very simply into a double-nested for loop.

The paper should also tell you what the mean/variance of the gaussian function is as well as the number of samples it contains, but sometimes that information is omitted.